# Word for a post-meeting 'justified prejudice'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which ultimately explains a dislike/hatred of a group of people, but unlike a prejudice can be justified through prior experiences and is potentially considered acceptable to express, which will fit in the following sentence:

'I am ....... against them'.

---

Interested in knowing if there is a way of communicating a dislike of certain groups of people without sounding ignorant and judgement like [prejudice](http://www.simplypsychology.org/prejudice.html) does:

> Prejudice is an unjustified or incorrect attitude (usually negative)
>   towards an individual based solely on the individual’s membership of a
>   social group.
>
> For example, a person may hold prejudiced views towards a certain race
>   or gender etc. (e.g. sexist).

---

I am aware that [discrimination](http://www.simplypsychology.org/prejudice.html) could potentially meet the requirements to some extent:

> Discrimination is the behavior or actions, usually negative, towards
>   an individual or group of people, especially on the basis of
>   sex/race/social class, etc.

However I believe this holds negative connotations itself, and expressing the fact you discriminate against groups of people is often frowned upon. Discriminate would not fit in the sentence anyway.

PS: I don't hold any negative views against anyone at all! Just curious if there is a word which meets my description. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't mind changing the sample sentence around a little, you could say that *you have (formed) a **considered opinion** against them*. I'm not sure how to wrench that term into your sample sentence, though.

Comment: Wouldn't _disapproval_ do?

Comment: I am ***biased*** against them.

Comment: What @Jim said. If you want to claim justification for your bias, then "*justifiably biased*".

Comment: What @Drew  said. ;-)

Comment: "wary" doesn't quite mean the same thing, but might work.